# Compile error on Property Wrapper in Swift 5.1

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, swift5, property-wrapper

I'm figuring out Property Wrappers in Swift, but I seem to miss something.

This is how I wrote a property wrapper for a dependency injection framework we use:

```swift
@propertyWrapper
struct Inject<Value> {
    var _value: Value

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            return _value
        }
        set {
            _value = newValue
        }
    }

    init(_ container: Container = AppContainer.shared) {
        do {
            _value = try container.resolve(Value.self)
        } catch let e {
            fatalError(e.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use it in my class like below, I get a compile error. I've seen a lot of examples that to me do the exact same thing but probably there are some differences.

```
class X: UIViewController {
    @Inject var config: AppConfiguration

    ....

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        config.johnDoSomething() // Compile error: 'AppConfiguration' is not convertible to 'AppConfiguration?'
    }
}
```

I few days ago I came across a reference that Xcode had compile issues with Generic Property Wrappers, but I can't find it anymore. I'm not sure if that's relevant but maybe somebody on SO can help me out.

Using Xcode 11.3.1

As requested, hereby a reprex (one file in playground):

```
import UIKit

/// This class is only to mimick the behaviour of our Dependency Injection framework.
class AppContainer {
    static let shared = AppContainer()

    var index: [Any] = ["StackOverflow"]

    func resolve<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
        return index.first(where: { $0 as? T != nil }) as! T
    }
}

/// Definition of the Property Wrapper.
@propertyWrapper
struct Inject<Value> {
    var _value: Value

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            return _value
        }
        set {
            _value = newValue
        }
    }

    init(_ container: AppContainer = AppContainer.shared) {
        _value = container.resolve(Value.self)
    }
}

/// A very minimal case where the compile error occurs.
class X {
    @Inject var text: String

    init() { }
}
```

Comment: Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: I've added a reprex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just dealing with your "reprex":

Change

```
@Inject var text: String
```

to

```
@Inject() var text: String
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I also had another error that made the PW not working. But that had something to do on using the `AppConfiguration` variable in a @objc function. Not sure why this didn't work as well, but at least it's now fixed.

Comment: There is no AppConfiguration in your "reprex" and that's all I'm dealing with here. The error you were making has to do with how explicit and implicit initializers work for property wrappers.